# Running Ruby XML Parse fired from incrontab

Tags: ruby, xml, json, bash, cron

I have an entry in incrontab that looks like this:

```
/var/www/html/tmp_files/xml IN_CLOSE_WRITE sh /var/www/html/tmp_files/notify.sh $# $@
```

In notify.sh we have:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="$1" 
csvname="fightcard.cmd.csv" 

if   [ "${filename:0:1}" == "$action" ]; then
                csvname="action.cmd.csv"
elif [ "${filename:0:1}" == "$stats" ]; then
                csvname="stats.cmd.csv"
else
        sleep 0.1
fi

#execute the ruby statement............
ruby /var/www/html/processXML.rb -f /var/www/html/tmp_files/xml/${filename} -c /var/www/html/${csvname} -l /var/www/html/tmp_files/logs/${filename}.log > /var/www/html/tmp_files/json/${filename%.xml}.json
```

I have chmodded notify.sh to executable.

So we ftp a file into `/var/www/html/tmp_files/xml/`

When I run the script from command everything works correctly like so:

```
sh /var/www/html/tmp_files/notify2.sh Stats.xml
```

but whenever it fires from the incrontab event, I end up with a blank json file.

anybody know what gives?

Comment: SOLVED@ i just needed to add the location of the ruby install itself to the command. /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby ruby /var/www/html/processXML.rb -f /var/www/html/tmp_files/xml/${filename} -c /var/www/html/${csvname} -l /var/www/html/tmp_files/logs/${filename}.log > /var/www/html/tmp_files/json/${filename%.xml}.json